# wp query check if user works on current company

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello i have two meta_keys for companies and one for company status if you work in present or not and i don't know how to make a query to verify that. Here are my two meta_keys and meta_value:

```
`key: cs_exp_company_array` `a:4:{i:0;s:10:"Websoft IT";i:1;s:10:"Websoft IT";i:2;s:14:"umbrella media";i:3;s:4:"csop";}`
```

and here is the key that tells if company is in present or not

```
key: cs_exp_to_present_array a:4:{i:0;s:2:"on";i:1;s:2:"on";i:2;s:2:"on";i:3;s:0:"";}
```

on it means you work in present for that company. Please tell me how to verify that.

Comment: could you write it bit more structured? If I have understood well, you have a `cs_exp_company_array` array with names of companies and `cs_exp_to_present_array`, but what is in the second array? That's not clear to me.

Comment: Second array tells if you work in present to that company, for each company it creates the second array and if it has "on" it means you work in present to that comp